# Storeboard image to SwiftUI

Tags: xcode, swiftui, storyboard

So I currently have my app using storyboard and am looking at changing it to swiftUI.

However I use ViewController to every 30seconds check a remote URL and change the data.

Now instead of recoding everything am wondering can you give a swiftUI image a @Object name like you can in Storyboard?

If so how as I can’t find any demo on YouTube.

My first thought is to make a custom class and have code in that class that refreshes every 30 seconds. Then somehow get it to update the image, artist (text) and song title (text).

Answer (score 0):

Try to learn and use UIHostingController it might help you.
UIHostingController allows us to use SwiftUI in UIKit

An article guide I found: [Use SwiftUI in UIKit View Controllers with UIHostingController](https://medium.com/@max.codes/use-swiftui-in-uikit-view-controllers-with-uihostingcontroller-8fe68dfc523b)